# How to get multiple POST data?

Tags: sql, post, input

I am trying to get the $_POST data from some inputs fields, but the thing is I am getting the number of fields from my database:

```
$query2 = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM params WHERE modulid = $parameterid");
$query2->execute();

<td>Parameter unit:</td>
<?php  while (($row2 = $query2->fetch()) != false)
  {
  $unit = $row2->name;
  ?><td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $row2->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $unit; ?>" class="textbox"></td><?php
  }
  ?>
```

What is the code to get post data from all of them so I can update the database if the user wants to type new data in the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all values submitted by a form by iterating through the following global variable:

```
$_POST
```

By using a foreach loop, you can then check which values were filled and generate an UPDATE SQL statement with them.

Example to get all non-empty values:

```
$changed = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($value)) {
        $changed[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Then create the query using the $changed array.

Comment: Ok got it to work...very elegant solution...thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like that

```
$temp=$row2->id;

mysql_query("insert into params (modulid) values ('$temp')");
```

Comment: But how am I getting the POST data (value which the user might input) from the fields with this code?

Comment: You can get the POST data as usual,see above there is something like that. Just get the $POST into a variable and then input it at your db with that code,i think it's very easy.